# Sorting in O(n log n) time using only minimum, successor, and insert explanation

Tags: algorithm

Found this question in The Algorithm Design Manual, and the solution to the question is

```
Sort2()
  initialize-tree(t)
  While (not EOF)
    read(x);
    insert(x,t);
  y = Minimum(t)
  While (y != NULL) do
    print(y → item)
    y = Successor(y,t)
```

and it's explained as *"The second problem allows us to use the minimum and successor operations after constructing the tree. We can start from the minimum element, and then repeatedly find the successor to traverse the elements in sorted order."*

I don't think I am following `Sort2()` here. If `y` is initialized to the minimum node, is it not true that there is a possibility it won't have any successor node? In the case that `y` only has a parent node, won't this code simply print out the mininum value in the tree `y` and then terminate?

Comment: if `y` does not have any successor nodes, then the tree only has one node and so yes, it should only print out the minimum value `y` and terminate

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding what the Successor function does -- it gets the next (sorted) node from the tree.  If there is no successor, then the node is the maximum node.  Getting the successor of a leaf involves looking at the parent of the leaf.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `y != NULL`?

Comment: @chepner you're right, it was a copy-and-paste typo. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of that algorithm is similar to heap sort:

1. Arrange all elements in a tree. You need `n` insertions that take `O(log n)` time each.
2. Traverse the tree. This can be done in `n` steps that take `O(1)` time each.

The point is that a tree is not a sequence, but it can be arranged in a way that allows iterating it in order, which makes it equivalent to a sequence.

Also, just in case that caused your confusion, the minimum node is not the root node but typically the leftmost leaf node!

Comment: A few clarifications: the elements need to be inserted into a (binary) search tree, not just a tree. To ensure an O(log n) insertion, it needs to be a balanced search tree. Finally, it's an in-order traversal, specifically, that produces the elements in sorted order. (As opposed to a pre- or post-order traversal.)